# How to connect SQLAlchemy (SQLDatabaseChain from langchain) to SingleStoreDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, langchain, singlestore

[SingleStoreDB](https://www.singlestore.com)
[langchain](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/popular/sqlite)
[more info from medium](https://medium.com/dataherald/how-to-langchain-sqlchain-c7342dd41614)

From local able to connect throught using this uri but in single store it is not working with same.

```
mysql+pymysql://user:pass@some_mysql_db_address/db_name
```

##### I wanted some kind of uri as below.

```
singlestore://user:pass@some_mysql_db_address/db_name
```

##### sample code:

```
import pymysql
from langchain import OpenAI, SQLDatabase, SQLDatabaseChain

user = 'root'
host='localhost'
password='password'
database='classicmodels_test'
local_uri = f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}"
```

##### Database connection:

```
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(local_uri)
print(db.table_info)
```

##### Output if connected

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    `customerNumber` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `customerName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    `contactLastName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    `contactFirstName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    phone VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    `addressLine1` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    `addressLine2` VARCHAR(50), 
    city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    state VARCHAR(50), 
    `postalCode` VARCHAR(15), 
    country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    `salesRepEmployeeNumber` INTEGER, 
    `creditLimit` DECIMAL(10, 2), 
    PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`), 
    CONSTRAINT customers_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY(`salesRepEmployeeNumber`) REFERENCES employees (`employeeNumber`)
)DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ENGINE=InnoDB
```

##### OR can we have databse connection object with pymysql function that supporting pymysql connection object

```
connection_obj = pymysql.connect(user='root',host='localhost', password='password', database='classicmodels_test')

SQLDatabase.connect(connection_obj)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

- create engine

  ```
  from sqlalchemy import create_engine

  engine = create_engine(CONNECTION_URL)
  ```
- connect db to SQLDatabaseChain

  ```
  from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
  from langchain.chains import SQLDatabaseChain

  db = SQLDatabase(engine)
  sql_chain = SQLDatabaseChain(llm=llm, database=db, verbose=True)
  ```
- you need a llm to pass to `SQLDatabaseChain`

  ```
  from langchain import OpenAI

  llm = OpenAI(
      openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
      temperature=0
  )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Notebook in SingleStoreDB Cloud Portal, you can use the following method:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
db_connection = create_engine(connection_url)
```

Make sure you pick the workspace and then the database.

You can also use the following connection if you want to connect locally:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
database_name = 'mydatabase'
connection_user = 'username'
connection_password = 'password'
connection_port = '3306'
connection_host = 'svc-XXXXX.svc.singlestore.com'
db_connection_str = "mysql+pymysql://"+connection_user+":"+connection_password+"@"+connection_host+":"+connection_port+"/"+database_name+"?ssl_cipher=HIGH"
db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)
```

**We use mysql connection not singlestore in url.**

Comment: I'm geting Error
```AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'```